# Iterate over list of data frames and delete columns and rows in every one of them

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, iteration, lapply

I have several data frames and I want to iterate over them and delete some columns and rows with more than 90% NAs in them. I played around with lapply as well but I cannot get it to work...

My current code is:

```
data_a_2007 <- read.csv(path)
data_a_2008 <- read.csv(path)
datasets_a <- list(data_a_2007, data_a_2008)

for(dataset in datasets_a) {
  columns_to_delete <- NULL
  rows_to_delete <- NULL

  # find columns threshold
  threshold_columns <- floor(nrow(dataset)*0.1)

  # find columns to delete
  valuecount_columns <- colSums(!is.na(dataset))
  columns_to_delete <- sort(which(valuecount_columns < threshold_columns), decreasing = TRUE)

  # find rows threshold
  threshold_rows <- floor(ncol(dataset)*0.1)

  # find rows to delete
  valuecount_rows <- rowSums(!is.na(dataset))
  rows_to_delete <- sort(which(valuecount_rows < threshold_rows), decreasing = TRUE)

  # delete columns with less than x values  
  for(column_id in columns_to_delete) {
    dataset[column_id] <- NULL
  }

  # delete rows with less than x values  
  for (row in rows_to_delete) {
    dataset <- dataset[-row,]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep rows/columns with e.g. less than 50% NAs:

```
# sample data
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(runif(1000), ncol = 5)
mat[sample(1:length(mat), length(mat)*.5)] <- NA
l <- split(as.data.frame(mat), gl(2, 100))

# NA threshold: <50%
NAthres <- 0.5

# keep columns with number of NAs below NA threshold:
l2 <- lapply(l, function(df) {
  cols <- apply(df, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
  return(df[, cols < (nrow(df) * NAthres)])
})


# keep rows with number of NAs below NA threshold:
l3 <- lapply(l, function(df) {
  rows <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))  
  df[rows < (ncol(df) * NAthres), ]
})
```

Comment: this works, thanks. didn't figure out that I had to use apply within the lapply. thank you!